# Calculate the probability of intersection basic probability theory

Tags: probability

The following information is known about the three events A,B and C.

$ P(A)=0.3, P(B)=0.2, P(C)=0.6, P(A \bigcup B \bigcup C)=1, P(A \bigcap C)=0, P(B \bigcap C)=0.1. $

Find $ P(A \bigcap B). $

What I have done so far:

My first attempt was to use the formula $ P(A \bigcup B)=P(A) + P(B) - P(A \bigcap B) $. But we don't know $ P(A \bigcup B) $ to use that. My second attempt was to use $ P(A \bigcup B \bigcup C) = P(A) + P(B)+P(C)-P(A \bigcap B) - P(B \bigcap C) - P(A \bigcap C) +P(A \bigcap B \bigcap C ) $ but to use that we do not know $ P(A \bigcap B \bigcap C ) $. What am I missing here?

$ P(X) $ denotes the probability of event $ X $.

Comment: If you're really stuck, since there are only three sets, you can draw a picture of three overlapping circles and fill in the given information.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Since $P(A\cap C) =0$, it must be true that $P(A\cap B\cap C) =0$ as well. Plug in the other known values to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple Venn's diagram you can see that

$P(B)=P(A \cap B)+P(B \cap C)$ so $P(A \cap B)=0.1$